# Custom title defined as layout: is there a way to set it via styles/theme?

Tags: android

If I define a custom theme using styles:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowTitleSize">@dimen/title_bar_height</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@drawable/titilebar_bg</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/bg_page</item> 
</style>
```

and also I have a special `titlebar.xml` which defines my title bar (buttons, icons, text etc) is there a way to set this layout as default layout for title bar in styles (like a default behavior for all activities)?

So that **I wouldn't have to add the following code in every single activity** (all activities actually):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.titlebar);
```

The only way I can see is to subclass Activity to inherit method which would make requestWindowFeature() among with onCreate()/setContentView(). But its not exactly what I'm asking about.

Answer (score 0):

Styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <style name="CustomWindowTitleBackground">
        <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/CustomWindowTitleBackground</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Mainfest.xml

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>
```

Comment: Are you trying to say that all I have to do is to rename my titlebar.xml to Title.xml? Cuz I can't see here any connection between the Title.xml and Styles and that was the point of my question but not the requestWindowFeature() stuff.

Comment: use Mainfest.xml, and Styles.xml, using both you can achieve Custom Title through out the Application.. I have used it Title.xml is not required.

Comment: Thanks but I know about it. The question is NOT about how to use custom theme or custom title. Its about using my titlebar.xml layout as title for the whole app. The question is about how to make it so that there is no need to call requestWindowFeature() method in every activity then I use the same title in all activities. So I guessed that I can set my titlebar.xml in styles.xml somehow and it would be enough.